# Does D3 Support a Compositional (bottom-up) Approach?

Tags: d3.js

Normally when I model things, say in a 3D scene graph, I describe low-level components first and then compose them into more and more complicated artifacts. For example, create a tire, then some lugnuts and then a hub and compose them together to define a wheel. Then take the wheel, body and engine and create a car. Finally, place the cars in the world.

D3, however, is usually expressed in a decomposition (top-down modeling). So it might have you create a table, then define its headers, then define its rows, then define the cells in each row.

There are advantages and disadvantages to both approaches, though for 3D modeling I've seen numerous novices get themselves tangled up trying to describe a complicated scene using top-down approaches. Much easier to think about low-level components in their own space, then then how to place and add them to their parent structures.

D3 is heavily biased against this, but I decided to try a compositional modeling approach anyway.

In short, it doesn't seem to be supported. To make concrete what I mean, I tried to create a table header component () first, and then afterwards append the table headers to a table element. I got this error message:

`Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('[object HTMLDivElement]') is not a valid name.`

I broke it down to a very simple example, and it still breaks.

```js
var component = document.createElement("div");
var d3component = d3.select(component).text("XYZZY");
var root = d3.select('#target');
// root.append(d3component);        // FAILURE
root.append('div').text("FROTZ");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="target"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you leave the `root.append(d3component)` line commented out, it runs successfully. However, if you uncomment it, D3 will fail with the above error message.

Am I missing something here, or is this approach truly unsupported by D3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having given this problem a second thought, I am not happy with my original answer, which I am going to keep at the end of this post, because it is correct, but it somehow begs the question of *"Does D3 Support a Compositional (bottom-up) Approach?"*. The answer should be *quite yes, but not really*.

- *Yes*, because D3 allows for mimicking a bottom-up approach by doing it the way you tried it. That failed for technical shortcomings, which can be cured as I explained in my original answer below, but this feels somewhat awkward and abusive. The main reason for this is, that D3 provides no means for explicitly *creating* elements. In most cases, DOM elements are created implicitly when doing an `.append()` or an `.insert()`. The only exception to this is providing a function to these methods which returns a DOM element created using methods outside of D3. It is important to understand, that this is not considered to be a deficiency but is by design.
- *Not really*, because at its core D3 is all about binding data to the hierarchy of a DOM tree. The concept of [selections](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections) allows for keeping your data and the corresponding part of the DOM in sync. This is done by obtaining a selection, binding data to it and use the *enter, update, exit scheme* to add or remove elements from the DOM. Furthermore, when adding elements to a selection or when doing a subselection in many cases data bound to a parent element will be inherited by its children. This calls for a strictly hierarchical top-down approach.

  Whether or not there is data involved, doing it the D3 way will start off with a selection be it initially empty or not (it may very well be `d3.select(document)` to start root-most) and add to or remove from it in a top-down fashion.

To cut a long story short, it is possible to mock a bottom-up approach using D3, though it wasn't designed to be used this way. If you decide to give it a try, keep in mind that it won't be neither the most elegant nor the most intuitive way, and is likely to introduce some overhead. To compose your layout in a bottom-up way it might be worth evaluating other libraries which might be better suited for this.

---

#### Original Answer

You cannot use `.append()` to add one of D3's selections to the DOM. You can, however, provide a function to `.append()` which [returns a DOM element](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#append) to be appended. This could be done by replacing the erroneous line with

```
root.append(function() { return component; });
```

Or, if you don't have a direct reference to the element, you may retrieve it from a selection

```
root.append(function() { return d3component.node(); });
```

Your example might then look like this

```js
var component = document.createElement("div");
var d3component = d3.select(component).text("XYZZY");
var root = d3.select('#target');
root.append(function() { return component; });
// ...or...
//root.append(function() { return d3component.node(); });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="target"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Wish I could upvote twice, since you really took on two tasks: figuring out the essential machinery to make it work, and then really addressing the fundamental design issue. Your insight about the lack of D3 methods to explicitly _create_ elements is key, I think.

I should also add that I don't consider this a flaw of D3, though I do believe that it's an interesting difference in philosophy. Whether it's simply because many people think top-down, or because it's considered undesirable to design bottom-up, I don't know.

Comment: @SteveHollasch Actually, it never occured to me that one could try it the other way round. This was a real brain-teaser, which kept me pondering for the last 24 hours. In fact, I am so accustomed to the D3 way, that I find it hard to imagine how and why this should reasonably be done bottom-up. I mean, I got your point, but to me it seems to be highly influenced by one's way of thinking, by the way you are used to tackle your tasks. Dealing with HTML or SVG I am not aware of any library or technology which does this stuff bottom-up when it comes to manipulating DOM trees.

Comment: D'oh, of course I should accept your reply as the answer. I need to use StackOverflow more. Regarding modeling bottom up, one would well argue that React.js does a bottom-up approach. That is, the render method constructs a component in its own world (and outside of the DOM), and then placement or multiple-instancing in the DOM is done elsewhere. In general, anything that constructs components without regard to their ultimate use is an example of bottom-up composition.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off with normal DOM selection, however it is possible with d3:

```js
var component = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","div"); // note use of createElementNS
d3.select(component).text("XYZZY");
var root = d3.select('#target');
root[0][0].appendChild(component);
root.append('div').text("FROTZ");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Any clarification why your solution works? Because D3 expects XHTML? Or because you used `root[0][0]`?

Comment: It looks like you don't need the `createElementNS` approach; the rest of the code causes this example to work.

Comment: The reason I chose to use createElementNS is that in my experience it is less of a memory hog in IE using it this way. `root[0][0]` gets the first element of the d3 selection as standard DOM object, which is why adding it works, That said, it is as easy to use `root.append(function() { return component })` as suggested by @altocumulus and may actually be clearer for you what is going on.